# How can I send a post request to my Laravel 4.2 app when submitting new order in wordpress, woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Laravel 4.2 app with REST API, And I want to save the orders in my app database by using api
How can I do this? Should I modify Woocommerce Plugin or do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possibility #1**

You need to make your own wordpress plugin and communicate with your Laravel app API endpoints.

Woocommerce receive order -> Plugin -> Curl -> Laravel API

I think there is ample information out there on how to create your own Wordpress plugin to do that, also you might want to look into the WooCommerce Documentation for relevant functions.

> https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-plugin-development-guide/
>
> https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api-updated--net-29785

**Possibility #2**

You can have a script on the Laravel APP side which will query the WooCommerce API and pull the latest WooCommerce orders.

> https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/
>
> https://gist.github.com/sisou/889971461616661d2ed6  (Laravel 4 Cron inspired from Laravel 5 scheduler)
>
> https://github.com/Indatus/dispatcher

**Important** : Never modify a core WordPress functions and avoid modifying any plugins (unless done with proper documentation and professional intent). This will avoid you further problem down the line you don't want and don't need. Also it is 99% of the time unnecessary since you can filter plugin functions and execute different task along any WordPress plugin.

Comment: by creating a wordpress plugin did you mean that i should use WooCommerce webhooks so?

Comment: In that context is that if you have a WooCommerce instance and want to send that information to a platform/service you can make a Wordpress Plugin and use the WooCommerce hooks and functions. I never got into using Webhooks but it is probably also a viable solution. (it all depends on your needs in the end).